# How to uncheck checked items in a matrix choice checkbox? (Wordpress/FormCraft plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am building a form for users to submit a list of their items that they want to move.

I use Wordpress with FormCraft Premium plugin which has the option to include a choice matrix (checkbox) in the form.

I want users to tell me how many beds do they have, how many night stands, how many mirrors, TVs, etc.

But the problem is that by default users can't uncheck a choice that they make.

So if a user selects accidentally that he has 4 TVs, he can't later uncheck that by clicking on that radio button again.
He is only able to select another radio button (1, 2, 3 or 5+) which is bad in cases when user doesn't have any TVs.

Could you please tell me how is it possible to fix this?

Here is the URL to my form: https://www.tajnezdravlja.com/form-view/4

I guess this can be solved only by using javascript.

I don't have any experience with javascript, I know only HTML and CSS.

I don't know where can I see any relevant code, as I don't have experience with .js

When I inspect the site and open console I don't see anything relevant.

However, the FormCraft plugin has an option to add custom javascript code to the form.

It says in admin panel:

Custom JavaScript
Add any JavaScript code in here, and it will be executed on page load. You don't have to use  tags. Make sure this is valid JavaScript!

When I click once on a choice, I expect it to be checked and that happens, that is ok.

But when I click again on the same choice, I expect it to become unchecked, but it remains checked. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to Custom JavaScript. It allows users to toggle the radio input type in the matrix fields.

```
jQuery('.fc-form .matrix-cover :radio').mousedown(function(e){
  var jQueryself = jQuery(this);
  if( jQueryself.is(':checked') ){
    var uncheck = function(){
      setTimeout(function(){jQueryself.removeAttr('checked');},0);
    };
    var unbind = function(){
      jQueryself.unbind('mouseup',up);
    };
    var up = function(){
      uncheck();
      unbind();
    };
    jQueryself.bind('mouseup',up);
    jQueryself.one('mouseout', unbind);
  }
});
```